# Download HTML as DOCX readable by Mac Pages

Tags: html, typescript, macos, download

I'm developing an application in Next.js with TypeScript, in which I want to let the user download a page as DOCX.

I was glad to find that it was possible to easily achieve this, using [this method](https://phppot.com/javascript/how-to-export-html-to-word-document-with-javascript/). The downloaded file can be opened by Microsoft Word, Google Documents and Libre Office, but when I try to open it with Pages on Mac, I get prompted that the file has an invalid format.

I guess this makes sense, given how the html headers seem pretty Microsoft oriented: "`<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' ... >`. However, I am really struggling with finding a way to download a DOCX which can be opened by Mac Pages.

There are third-party options like [html-to-docx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-docx) which might be able to handle this, but I'm having trouble finding any such (maintained) package with type declarations for TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [html-to-docx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-docx) anyway, ignoring the lack of type declarations for now, by `@ts-ignore`:ing the import. It seems like the package has [type definitions on its way](https://github.com/privateOmega/html-to-docx/pull/122) though.

The package manages to download the given HTML page as DOCX readable on all platforms I've tested this far (Word, Google Documents, Libre Office and Mac Pages).